# How do I factor user input in a loop

Tags: python

I've been doing well but do not understand how to do this. pls help, thx.
Write a program that lets a user enter N and that outputs N! (N factorial, meaning N*(N-1)*(N-2)*...*2*1). Hint:Use a loop variable i that counts from total-1 down to 1. Compare your output with some of these answers: 1:1, 2:2, 3:6, 4:24, 5:120, 8:40320.

```
N = int(input())  #read user-entered number

total = N

#initialize the loop variable

while i = ?:

    # Set total to total * (i)
    # Decrement i
    print(total)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See where the assignment says "Hint:Use a loop variable i that counts from total-1 down to 1."? So if it counts down *from* `total - 1` *to* `1`, then: what should it be set to before the loop starts? What rule should be used to decide when to exit the loop? What should happen to `i` each time through the loop? Then, how do you write the code for that? If you "have been doing well" then I am sure you can handle this; after all, the other questions in your assignment also involved loops, right?

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822. Make sure you understand that this is not a discussion forum, and we need you to turn your homework problem into a *specific question* - "pls help, thx" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a school/uni question so I won't answer this directly.

Given some number `N`, you want to calculate the factorial of `N`, aka the result of multiplying together every number from `1` to `N` inclusive.

It might help however to think of this in reverse (i.e. start at `N` and multiply by `(N-1)`, then `(N-2)` and so on, until you get to `1`).

So think about what you want the value of `i` to start off as, and then what value of `i` you want the loop to stop running at.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The assignment is probably for school, but there is no *question* being *asked*, and thus no reason to answer. Please read [answer] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/ for more guidance.